# Find and get bold text in richtextbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm new to C# and I need to find those text that is on bold/italic or undderline in my richtextbox. Any idea how?

The only thing I know is get using contains, but is there any way I can get it correctly.

```
richTextBox2.Text = browser.Div(Find.ByClass("GWTCKEditor-Disabled") && Find.ByIndex(2)).GetAttributeValue("outerHTML");

                if (richTextBox2.Text.Contains(@"<b>"))
                {


                    BoldUnderlineItalic = 0;
                }
```

Comment: You can try to use a HTML parser library like AngleSharp.

Comment: is there any other way? like a simple one without using a library?

Comment: You can still rely on a regex to parse html, [but](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1248177)...

Comment: What [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) / [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) / ??? are you talking about?

Comment: the 2nd one. any idea?